# Is there a way to download the zip code from AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I want to take the backup of lambda code to s3 periodically using node JS code.

i tried searching for Node JS SDk API's, i was not able to find any solution.

It would be great if someone suggest me the solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**[lambduh-get-s3-object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambduh-get-s3-object)** package can get the work done for you.

This package expects three fields on the passed options object: `.srcBucket`, `.srcKey`, and .`downloadFilepath`

By default this will use the default region the lambda operates in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,  I want to download the code from lambda which is already uploaded in deployment package.

Comment: Please check my edited post, and try out the package which will be helpful for you.